# swiper.js - slide CSS animation issue on slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need help - I have to apply CSS animation on swiper.js .

1. When swiper slide come on current slide all element apply fade In effect.
2. When swiper slider leave current slider all element apply fade out effect before leaving the current slider.

All slide will come with same effect, please help

```
var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';
swiper.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', function () {
var swiperIndex = swiper.activeIndex;

switch(swiperIndex){
case 0:
var findele = $('.slide-1').find(".animated");
findele.each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.addClass('fadeInDown', 700).on(animEndEv, function() {
$this.removeClass('fadeInDown');
});
});
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li').removeClass('active');
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li.link1').addClass('active');
break;

case 1:
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li').removeClass('active');
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li.link2').addClass('active');
break;

case 2:
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li').removeClass('active');
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li.link3').addClass('active');
break;

case 3:
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li').removeClass('active');
$('.swiper-pagination-bullets-manual li.link4').addClass('active');
break;

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@bahman: Please host demo in an online editor for more visibility towards the problem